# How to count number of typed character in textarea using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I don't know why inner HTML is not working when I put it inside function but it works fine when I try the same in my console.

Here is my code. (It is for character count.)

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("input-content").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("input-content")[i].onkeyup = function () {
        console.log(this);
        var text_max = 99;
        var text_length = this.value.length;
        var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
        document.getElementsByClassName("character-count")[i].innerHTML = "Character count:" + text_length + "/" + text_max;
    }
}
```

My HTML

```
<textarea type="text" class="input-content"></textarea>
<p class="character-count"></p>
```

I know this may be something silly which I am missing out.

PS: I'm looking for a pure JavaScript answer. Please don't suggest jQuery.

UPDATE: It works fine when i do not use onkeyup event but the count doesnot increase

```
    for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByClassName("input-content").length;i++)
{
 var text_max = 99;
 var text_length = document.getElementsByClassName("input-content")[i].value.length;
 var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
 document.getElementsByClassName("character-count")[i].innerHTML="Character count:" +text_length+"/"+text_max;    
 }
```

Comment: Your document needs to load before you can use this script. Your JavaScript should be at the bottom of the page, and defined inside a window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){ });

Comment: this.innerHTML will put the content inside input-content which i do not want. I want it in character-count

Comment: the index of the class of `character-count` is not necessarily the same as for `input-content`. i suggest to use `document.getElementById` and add it's attribute with appropriate content.

Comment: From what i've seen you can't use .innerHtml on document.getElementByClassName()

Comment: @nina The index will always be same and i cannot use ID because whatever element i create on the page there are 2 copies.(one for mobile which i hide on desktop view) and there cant be 2 ID. I need to do it with class names only..:(

Comment: @Dibsy You can use use .innerHtml on document.getElementByClassName()....change it to document.getElementsByClassName()[0] or document.getElementsByClassName()[1] or so on. as it gives an array

Comment: @bashaus It works fine when i do not use onkeyup event listener. Please see the update. But the count doesnot increases but i can get the text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a closure for the index:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("input-content").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("input-content")[i].onkeyup = function (i) {
        return function () {
            console.log(this);
            var text_max = 99;
            var text_length = this.value.length;
            var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
            document.getElementsByClassName("character-count")[i].innerHTML = "Character count:" + text_length + "/" + text_max;
        };
    }(i);
}
```

```html
<textarea type="text" class="input-content"></textarea>
<p class="character-count"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks Nina. I want it cross browser. Will you be able to give a solution for this? It works fine for Chrome but not on ie

Comment: which version are you usinf? it runs on my ie11 and edge.

Comment: I am on ie9 and it does not work..:( Its in pure javascript still not working in ie9 its little weird

Comment: and what part is not working? according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName#Browser_compatibility), it should work for `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: the javascript for that particular part is not working.I am not able to see Character left: 0/99 at all. I keep on typing and it gets typed. There is no text coming below.

Comment: do you have checked the console with f12? are there any errors?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that when you are binding the `keyup`function, you are using `i` as an index for the `character-count` element. But when you do press a key, `i` is undefined at that point and so there is no index. You could do it like this, by setting an attribute (I used `name`) and when you do press a key, get that attribute and use it as an index.

```js
textareas = document.getElementsByClassName("input-content");
charCounts = document.getElementsByClassName("character-count");

for (var i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
  textareas[i].setAttribute("name", i);
  textareas[i].onkeyup = function() {
    var text_max = 99;
    var text_length = this.value.length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
    charCounts[this.getAttribute("name")].innerHTML = "Character count: " + text_length + "/" + text_max;
  }
}
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="input-content"></textarea>
<p class="character-count"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your textareas in a group so that you don't have to rely on siblings ...

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hntmxLxu/

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var groups = document.querySelectorAll(".textarea-group");

    function attachListener(group) {
        group.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('keyup', function () {
            group.querySelector('.textarea-group--characters').innerHTML = this.value.length;
        });
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; ++i) {
        attachListener(groups[i]);
    }
});
```

And the HTML ...

```
<div class="textarea-group">
    <textarea cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
    <p class="textarea-group--characters"></p>
</div>

<div class="textarea-group">
    <textarea cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
    <p class="textarea-group--characters"></p>
</div>
```